# In JWT Authorization, check if user has role Admin

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

I am working on a .Net Core API, and inside my Controller, I have the following code:

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var username = HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
    artistCardDtoCollection = _artistsService.GetAllArtists(user.Id, User.IsInRole("Admin"));
}
```

The code above is because I wish to pass the `User.Id` (if logged in) and a `IsAdmin` flag to my `GetAllArtists` method.

The code above is failing on `User.IsInRole("Admin")`. I get a `false` when I know 100% that the user in question is an **Admin**. I've *double checked* the database via SQL Management Studio.

This makes me think one can't use `User.IsInRole()` when working with JWT. If that is the case, then what is the correct way? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it could be the caching issue with `User.IsInRole()`, if we check [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprincipal.isinrole(v=vs.110).aspx) we will find:

> IsInRole **first** checks the **IsRoleListCached** property to determine
>   whether a cached list of role names for the current user is available.
>   If the IsRoleListCached property is true, the cached list is checked
>   for the specified role. If the IsInRole method finds the specified
>   role in the cached list, it returns true. If IsInRole does not find
>   the specified role, it calls the GetRolesForUser method of the default
>   Provider instance to determine whether the user name is associated
>   with a role from the data source for the configured ApplicationName
>   value.

In your case you can try to use `GetRolesAsync` like below:

```
var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
artistCardDtoCollection = _artistsService.GetAllArtists(user.Id, roles.Contains("Admin"));
```

Comment: Would both `_userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);` and `_userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);` make a call to the Database? so two calls to the Db. Also doesn't the cache get cleared if I stop and start the application?

Comment: Your code works. The `IsAdmin` flag is now being set to true.

Comment: @Ciwan Yes, 2 queries. In order to get Role name via 1 query we should  make 2 joins, 1st to get roles and 2nd to get role name by id. And here we have 1 simple query for User  and 1 with 1 join for RoleName, so it should be almost the same in time(I measured it). `GetRolesAsync` generate next SQL: `SELECT [role].[Name]
FROM [AspNetUserRoles] AS [userRole]
INNER JOIN [AspNetRoles] AS [role] ON [userRole].[RoleId] = [role].[Id]
WHERE [userRole].[UserId] = @userId`, so you can just pass `new ApplicationUser { id = userid}` with just ID,not the whole User object and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @Ciwan No problems, glad that it helped you :)